# Persistence Message Queue behavior with no subscribers (ActiveMQ)

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

We develop NMS product that has been deployed by couple of telecom operators. Our application (uses ActiveMQ) will publish Fault notifications to the Fault Queue, the messages are set to be persistent. These messages are consumed by third party JMS clients. Not all the customers will have a notification client to consume the events(some of the deployments will not have any subscriptions). The question is, does ActiveMQ persist the messages if the queue never had a subscriber connected to the Queue?.

Answer (score 0):

The Broker will persist messages to a Queue regardless of the presence of consumers when the message is tagged as persistent.  That is the general contract of the Queue model.